# How to programmatically tap a UIImageView in unit tests?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

In XCTest I need to simulate tapping on a UIImageView. For UIButton I use `sendActionsForControlEvents` method:

```
sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

But it looks like UIImageView does not have this method. Is there a way to simulate tapping on UIImageView in XCTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override touchesEnded function

```
  override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let node: SKNode = nodeAtPoint(location)
            if node.name == "Scale" {

            }
        }
    }
```

and get the tapped element from its location.